# Grant create any table to xxx in oracle

Tags: plsql, permissions, sql-grant

I am triyng to run this script on schema 1:

GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO schema2;

GRANT INSERT ANY TABLE TO schema2;

but I get this error :

> > GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO schema2
> > Error at line 1
> > ORA-01031: Nicht ausreichende Berechtigungen

what should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` means that the user you are connected as doesn't have privileges to perform the action you are attempting to do. So in this case `SCHEMA1` doesn't have the privileges to `GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE` to any schema.

If you connect as SYS, SYSTEM, or another privileged user, you can then run the grant `GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO SCHEMA1 WITH ADMIN OPTION;`. Then if you connect to `SCHEMA1`, you should then be able to run `GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO schema2;`. The same procedure will need to be done for the `INSERT ANY TABLE` privilege.